# Working with legacy databases and SchemaAction in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have two classes:

```
public class User
{
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Report
{
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

... where class `User` already is an existing table in the database. Now, I want to add `Report` as a table to the database, and for this I plan to use Fluent NHibernate. I'm mapping both `User` and `Report`, since I want `User` to be accessible from the `Report` class. There is a one-to-many relationship between `User` and `Report`.

I already have tests which export SQL scripts to the database and `User` is included in these. Now I also want to export the scripts generated by FNH but I don't want FNH to generate `User`, since it's already in the database.

Therefore, I can specify `SchemaAction.None()` in the mapping for `User`. This makes FNH not generate script for `User`, only for `Result`. The only problem is, no foreign key is generated in the table `Report`. How can I make FNH not export generated script for `User` but still export the foreign key for the table `Report`?

If I simply not specify SchemaAction, tables `User` and `Report` are created and the foreign key in `Report` is generated.

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but why do you want to use two different methods to create the complete schema? Why not simple add to the existing mechanism?

Comment: The existing mechanism is table scripts created by hand. Quering the database is made through stored procedures - created by hand. Needless to say, implementing NHibernate along with the current mechanism will save time in the future.

Comment: I use NHibernate very much. But I've so far never used the SchemaExport in production scenarios, because I find that often additional ad-hoc SQL is required to adapt existing data when the schema is modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. copy the old/existing schema into a new database
2. create an NHibernate Configuration with your mappings and the existing database
3. use this code to write the update script into a file

   ```
   using (var file = new StreamWriter("SchemaUpdateScript.txt"))
   {
       new SchemaUpdate(config).Execute(file.WriteLine, false);
   }
   ```
4. double check that the update script really does what you want

Point 1. is optional. I would strongly advice against using SchemaUpdate directly in production environment.